# Set Sort order for Product Images and Save Programatically

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, product-images

I have an option to add products and its images in frontend. All the product details are saved correctly.But I want to set sort order for each image.

Below is the code to store product images,it's working good. But with this I want to set sort order also.

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$files)
{
    $absolute_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.$f.DS.$s.DS.$files;

                $mediaArray = array(
                        'thumbnail'   => $absolute_path,
                        'small_image' => $absolute_path,
                        'image'       => $absolute_path,
                    );
                    foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $files)
                    {
                        $filePath = $files;
                        if(file_exists($filePath)) 
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false, false);
                            } 
                            catch (Exception $e)
                            {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
                        }
                  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With addImageToMediaGallery it is not possible to add position to the image,

you will need to use media->getBackend()->updateImage() after uploading the image,

but updateImage() needs second parameter image path of the uploaded image,

you can get it with media->getBackend()->addImage() it returns the filename, have a look at code for some hints

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123);

$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);

$media_gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];

$backend = $media_gallery->getBackend();

$backend->afterLoad($product);

$count = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages()) + 1;

if($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){
    $media_attributes = null;
}else{
    $media_attributes = array('image','small_image','thumbnail');
}
$filename = $media_gallery->getBackend()->addImage($product, $import, $mediaAttribute,false, false);
$attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filename, array('position' => $count));

$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

after add  update image details by below code

```
 $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
$attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $file, $data=array('postion'=>yourpostion,'label'=>'yourlabel'));
```

this code need add after

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false, false);
```

Comment: I added this but not working

Comment: try
      {
       $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false, false);
       $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
      $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filePath, $data=array('postion'=>1,'label'=>'images'));
$product->save();      }

Comment: After saving products we use this or before

Answer (score 0):

```
   $sku             =  "test";   
  $product         =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku );

                if(is_object($product) )
                {

                      $baseImage                  =  $value[1];
                      $fullBaseImage              = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'import'.DS.'HSD-optimized-images-toupload-1'.DS.$baseImage; 

                      $additionalImage            =  $value[2];
                      $fullAdditionalImage        = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'import'.DS.'HSD-optimized-images-toupload-1'.DS.$additionalImage;


                    $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
                    $media_gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
                    $backend = $media_gallery->getBackend();
                    $backend->afterLoad($product);
                    $count = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages()) + 1; 



                      if($baseImage!='' && is_file($fullBaseImage)  )
                      {
                            $media_attributes = array('image','small_image','thumbnail');
                            $filename = $media_gallery->getBackend()->addImage($product, $fullBaseImage, $media_attributes,false, false);
                            $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filename, array('position' => $count));
                            $product->save();


                      }
                      else if($additionalImage!='' && is_file($fullAdditionalImage)  )
                      {
                            $filename = $media_gallery->getBackend()->addImage($product, $fullAdditionalImage, null,false, false);
                            $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filename, array('position' => $count));
                            $product->save();

                      }


                }
```